# How to type special characters in Linux when Russian layout is active?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, unicode, input

The way to type special unicode characters in Linux is to press `Ctrl + Shift + u` and then to type the character number.

But this method doesn't work when Russian layout is active. So if I'm typing in Russian and I want to input a special unicode character I have to switch to English layout then type the character and then switch back to Russian layout.

Is there any way to make `Ctrl + Shift + u` work in Russian layout as well?